# Comprobar si el valor de una celda también está en el valor de cualquier celda que esté dentro de un rango

Tags: excel

Quisiera saber si hay alguna forma de lograr esto con fórmulas.

Si tengo una celda, vamos a llamarle `CA` por ejemplo, quisiera comparar su valor con todos los valores que hay en otra columna y si el valor de una de las celdas de la columna es igual al valor de `CA`, entonces colocar un texto u otro valor.

No puedo hacerlo con `IF` anidados porque tendría que hacer `CA=n1,CA=n2..CA=n` tendría que comparar `CA` con todas las columnas de forma estática.

Quisiera que fuera más o menos así:

```
SI(CA=n1:n12) //Si CA es igual a uno de los valores en ese rango
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Puedes utilizar [la función `O`](https://support.microsoft.com/es-es/office/o-funci%C3%B3n-o-7d17ad14-8700-4281-b308-00b131e22af0) para averiguar si dentro de un rango hay un valor coincidente
:

```
=SI(O($A$1:$A$24=CA1);"SI";"NO")
```

Esto indica si hay o no coincidencias. Puedes cambiar el "SI" para que cambie el valor de la celda.

Comment: He probado la respuesta y no funciona: [![error al implementar la solución](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hname.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hname.png) Por si fuera un error dpor culpa de mi versión excel comentar que trabajo en 2016 Plus

Answer (score 1):

Debes utilizar la fórmula coincidir junto con `SI.ERROR()` así:

`=SI.ERROR(COINCIDIR(A1;A2:H2;0);"No existe")`

Te sirve tanto para números como texto y te devuelve la columna/fila (según si buscas en filas o columnas) en la que está contando desde 1 a partir de la primera celda del rango:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

Otra forma sería con la función `CONTAR.SI(rango_dónde_buscar;valor_buscado)` además te diría cuantas veces aparece.

Si quieres un texto pues combinas con la función SI: `SI(CONTAR.SI(rango_dónde_buscar;valor_buscado)>0;"Aparece en la lista";"No aparece en la lista")`